# try-except function in notebook databricks

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, databricks

thanks for you time

I am using Databricks and I am trying to do a Try-Except function of the following type:

```
while True:
    try:
        sdf_report=spark.createDataFrame(df_report)
        sdf_report.write.jdbc(jdbcDash,'dbo.table_name','append') #overwrite or append
        break
    except ValueError:
         None
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work as I want, since it never finishes executing my notebook and I need that in case the dataframe is empty, an error does not occur and my notebook ermine 'succedded'

Please recommend me a method?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If there is an error, then you'll never leave the `while` loop. You probably don't need a loop at all based on your example code...

Comment: ok I understand. What statement should I add to get out of the loop? is not a break? thanks!

Comment: Why do you need the loop in the first place?

Comment: ok I understand you. Thanks, it's already solved.